# How can I make a listview with individual row properties in XAML?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, listview, expression-blend

Here is a mock-up of what I am looking to do:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1nw78dqxuulvq73/Tree-01.png

Here is the code that I have so far in XAML (although I don't think I'm approaching the problem properly):

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="CCListView.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource CustomListViewItemStyle}"
          AlternationCount="2" Background="black" BorderThickness="0">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ContInfo}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

    <ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem.FontSize>15</ListViewItem.FontSize>
        <ListViewItem.Foreground>black</ListViewItem.Foreground> 
        <ListViewItem.Content>test</ListViewItem.Content>     
    </ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>       

</ListView>

    <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource CustomListViewItemStyle}"
          AlternationCount="2" Background="black" BorderThickness="0">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ContInfo}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

    <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>       

</ListView>
</Grid>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks! VisDae

Comment: I think you should use TreeView instead of ListViews as that image shows a Tree View.

Comment: Can I individually control the row styling with treeview though? I think you may be right for formatting.

Comment: This is another example of a listview, I think this one would work better as a listview than a tree though so am curious on your thoughts:

[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rg0fgckncmyhlc/ListEXdata-01.png

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using a GroupStyle and a CollectionViewSource binding.

Refering to the names on your sample picture,
you would need to have a viewmodel for your "Group" object. In that viewmodel, you would have an ObservableCollection of "Item" objects.

You would then have a CollectionViewSource in the Resources section of your window, that is bound to a collection of Group objects. Then create a GroupStyle for your ListBox, which can target DataTemplates to format the data in your ListBox.

I know I probably haven't explained this very well, so I've included a link to a project that has similar functionality.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx